# How to find the shortest path in a weighted graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I need to find the shortest path from A to Z in this graph.

I got $18$ but that does not seem to be the right result.

Would be glad for any help.

[image]

Comment: How did you get that number? Are you familiar with Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: Yes I am. Which number did you get?

Comment: In case you need a refresher, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdmfOwyQlcI is a good explanation.

Comment: I would very much prefer the result.

Comment: What makes you think that the result is incorrect?  Did someone else say it was wrong?  We aren't going to simply do your homework, but we can explain how to do it.

Comment: Because I traced the path back to A and it does not give 18. This is not my homework, I just need to know the result as fast as possible so if anybody could give me what they think is the correct result while explaining why they think so, I would be much obliged.

Comment: 18 is the fastest I found.

Comment: What is your path ? Why are you in such a  hurry if it is not a homework ?

Comment: the Dijkstra algorithm is simply the breadth-first search where the weights are converted to a corresponding number of edges. so the real problem is to understand the breadth-first search algorithm.

Comment: Check out this tutorial on Dijkstra's Algorithm: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/386358-dijkstras-algorithm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the result of Dijkstra's Algorithm using $a$ as the source.

[image: Result of Dijkstra's Algorithm]

The shortest path is $abdfklmjngiz$ for a total of $3+2+1+2+1+1+1+1+2+1+3=18$

Comment: Thank you. The way I got 18 was that I went: abdfhz and then I went this way back which did not give me 18 so that made me think it wasnt the correct number. I also wasnt sure whether I could go from M "back up" to j to decrease it to 11 since going to j from either b or c gave me 12.

Comment: This is not a directed graph, so of course you can "go back up."  Only if arrows are included on the edges should you be concerned about direction you travel.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me : )

Comment: As for going abdfhz, that works as well.  When there is a tie, it doesn't matter which of the two paths you add next.